# Specifying section font size in points

Tags: packages, fontsize

I'm writing a paper for a conference that requires section headings to have a certain format, with the font size specified in points. There seem to be two packages for changing the fonts of section headings, `titlesec` and `sectsty`. However, with `sectsty` I can't work out how to make subsubsection headings non-bold (which I also need), and with `titlesec` I can't see how to specify the font size in points, rather than just as "big", "medium", etc.

For completeness, what I need to do is this:

- typeset `\section` headings in 11pt bold
- typeset `\subsection` headings in 10pt bold
- typeset `\subsubsection` headings in 10pt roman
- remove the whitespace following `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` headings.

What is the best way to achieve these effects, using either package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `sectsty` it's difficult to change the spacings; with `titlesec` one has to rebuild all headings. Probably copying the definitions from `article.cls` and modifying them is the easiest way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\fontsize{10.95}{13.6}\bfseries}% 11pt
}
\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {1sp}% No space after subsections
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% normal size, boldface
}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {1sp}% No space after subsubsections
                {\normalfont\normalsize}% normal size, medium
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum} % to provide mock text

\begin{document}
\section{This is large boldface}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{This is normal size boldface}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{This is normal size medium}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `1sp` for getting zero space is just a trick: if we put `0pt`, the heading would be in line (an optimization trick used by LaTeX not to increase the number of arguments). But 1sp is just indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I'll leave the question open for a bit in case someone has a better answer (this one feels like a little bit of a hack, but that's nitpicking), and if not I'll accept this. By the way, where do the numbers come from in the \fontsize{10.95}{13.6} command?

Comment: @Nathaniel They come from the setting used from LaTeX for 11pt type size (see the file `size11.clo`). The interline skip (13.6pt) is relevant only if the section title needs to be split across lines.